# "Maybe we're both still inside."

Tags: babylon-5

I just recently started to watch (struggle) through babylon 5 - and one quote at the end of an early episode caught my attention:

> "There's something in my head. It says .. maybe you're still inside. Maybe we're both still inside."
>  
>  — Knight Two in Babylon 5:"And the Sky Full of Stars"

I tried to look up some informations about this, but I couldn't quite find anything yet. No relevant wiki trivia or anything - just a repeat of the quote.

**Is this ever followed upon or mentioned again later in the series? Are they?**

Judging by the episodes following, I'ld say it's unlikely that:

> They are all just a [virtual reality / dream / whatever else] the quote implies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Not mentioned again. The Lurker's Guide offers some thoughts...

You may be aware of the comprehensive [**Lurker's Guide**](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/) (aka **"Midwinter"**), which stores *B5* episode synopses, analyses, and various musings of JMS himself.  It is not "official", but JMS has interacted with it and, in many instances, supplied statements directly to it.

On the matter of your quote:

> Knight Two apparently remembered nothing about himself after Sinclair's destructive escape fried his memory. However, the word "Commander" brings him up short, and he remembers Sinclair's name, saying "There's something in my head. It says: 'Maybe you're still inside. Maybe we're both still inside.'" His phrasing there indicates that this is not his own current thought, but a thought that survived his brain damage. So, what did Knight Two, in full possession of his faculties, mean by that suspicion? The most obvious answer is "inside the simulation," but this is a very weak explanation, and goes nowhere.

([Source](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/008.html))

These musings don't provide a solid explanation, and I can confirm (having watched the series in it's entirety more than once) that these particular comments of Knight Two are not revisited.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the guide, so I appreciate the link! It's too bad that it's never followed up - But it's also understandable... suddenly revealing that a whole season (or multiple seasons) worth of episodes were just a simulation probably wouldn't fare well with most. That's why I wondered in the first place!

Comment: @Katai : There's a mountain of info in the Lurker's Guide.  Have fun!  :-)

Comment: It seems clear enough that Knight Two thinks that they are or might still be inside the simulation.  But that's presumably just paranoia caused by the brain damage, I don't think it was meant to have any significance to the plot.  (And it *is* [a very common trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SchrodingersButterfly), after all.  **Warning:** TV Tropes link.)